# Not able to convert JPG image to PNG format

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this method to convert JPG images to PNG but not converting its saved to the gallery but in JPG format only

```
       getImages() async {
        File _image;
        final pickedFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        setState(() {
          if (pickedFile != null) {//
          img.Image image = decodeImage(pickedFile.readAsBytesSync());
          img.Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, width: 120);
            _image = File(pickedFile.path)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(thumbnail));
            print("_image.path");
            print(_image.path);
            GallerySaver.saveImage(_image.path, albumName: 'Image Resizer')
                .then((bool success) {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: "Image saved",
                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16.0);
            });
            print('_image');
            print(_image.toString());
          } else {
            print('No image selected.');
          }
          return _image;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same image name and extension to save, that is why the image is saving with jpg extension.

You need to pass the path as well as the image name with extension as png.

```
_image = File(pickedFile.path)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(thumbnail));
```

The above code should be as below.

```
_image = File("path_to_folder/imageName.png")..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(thumbnail));
```